# Kotlin: get( path: . . .) Unresolved Reference: path

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, kotlin, maven-plugin

I am new to Kotlin and I walking through and example of such . . .

```
package com.example.lambda1

import spark.Spark.get

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, World")
    get( path: "/hello") { req, res -> "Hello World" } }
```

I am using IntellJ Community Edition

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-183.4284.148, built on November 20, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b15 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

When creating the new project, I selected "Maven" from within "IJ" and click on "Create from archtype" and selected "org.jetbrains.kotlin-archetype-jvm".

POM File have been updated to . . .

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.10</kotlin.version>
    <kotlin.code.style>official</kotlin.code.style>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <spark.version>2.6.0</spark.version>
</properties>
```

I add the "spark.version" here.  Not sure of the version consider the recording of the video creation date.

And I added the following

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

It seems to be a "maven/spark" issue, for I run a kotlin hello world app just fine.

Comment: Do you mean `get(path = "/hello")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're copying the code from a video, "path:" is a parameter name hint inserted by the IDE. It's not part of the source text, and you should not type it in when you copy the code.

Answer (score 1):

As @yole said, this `path:` is a parameter name hint. Then you can just ignore that,

```
get("/hello") { req, res -> "Hello World" }
```

or explicitly specify the parameter name.

```
get(path = "/hello") { req, res -> "Hello World" }
```

Comment: Wow, deleted the "path:" the system immediately populated it.  Thank you @yole and Geno Chen.